# How to assign a set of value in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to do such a job:
In MySQL statement, try to assign a set of values (1, 6, 68, 76, 43) in this order to a variable a. 
That is: 
    in a lop,
    first, a=1 do the loop
    then a=6 do the loop
    then a=68 do the loop
    and so on.

Can anyone show me how to do it? Thanks

Comment: Is this list likely to change?

Comment: No, will be a hard coded list

Comment: The linked duplicate topic explains how to process a list of values provided in a single string where the values are separated by comma. Just use the same logic with a hard coded string of your values.